# How to prevent Django messages from leaking out to other modules?

Tags: python, django, message

I am currently using the built-in `django-messages` framework of django version `1.10`.

However, since the messages are stored in the request, and therefore not "namespaced" as it were for different modules, I am concerned that this might lead to potential circumstances where messages created by one module (e.g. a messaging framework "your message has been sent") might bleed into another.

Is there a way to "namespace" these messages so we dont have this unintended affect?

In addition, the documentation says that messages expire if they are iterated over, does that mean that if I forget to iterate over them, they have the potential to build up over multiple requests?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your namespace issue - since all messages are simply stored in the request, and are managed by sessions - they are in the request namespace. Any object that manipulates the request (and thus, the session) can add messages. I don't know what kind of additional namespacing you would need, as messages are not for inter-module communication (use an external cache or message bus for that). However, you can add custom tags to any message to further differentiate them. Message are cleared automatically once the response is processed, so they don't build up.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How do I prevent messages I add in the `email` module from being inadvertently displayed in the `account` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over messages to expire them. Django does that for you.

When one `request` gets a `message` it's iterated over with the next `request`, gets displayed if the template allows it and is removed from `request` data. That means it's shown once and is removed.

The only way to get a `message` from your `email` module to be displayed in the `account` module is to redirect the user to an `account` page directly after the action that adds the `message` has been completed (after an email has been sent, for example). You have complete control over this from your `views`.